# Younger to me vs Younger than me

Tags: prepositions

I found many peoples using "**to**" in place of "**than**" on Internet/facebook.

> He is younger to me.
>
> He is younger than me.

Is this correct? I guess using "**to**" changes the meaning of sentence. I think It would imply ***To me(in my eyes) he is younger***

Comment: "younger to me" makes me wonder where the rest of the comparison is.  "younger to me **than** somebody..."

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you. I think that the people who say "He is younger to me.", unless they mean what you suggest, are not native English speakers.

Answer (score 2):

'younger than' is the correct usage.

'younger' is a **comparative adjective**, which as the name suggests, are used to compare differences between the two objects they modify (larger, smaller, faster, higher). They are used in sentences where two nouns are compared, in this pattern:

**Noun (subject) + verb + comparative adjective + *than* + noun (object).**

Examples:

- Today is hotter than yesterday.
- I am taller than Bob.
- I can run faster than my friend.

The second item of comparison can be omitted if it is clear from the context

- My friend and I have dogs. My dog is bigger. *('than his dog' can be
  omitted)*